# CMake Target Link Library "Could NOT find GLUT (missing: GLUT_glut_LIBRARY)"

Tags: c++, c, cmake

Following is my cmake file on which I get the error "Could NOT find GLUT (missing: GLUT_glut_LIBRARY)". I guess there is problem with my target link library. What exactly am I doing wrong ?

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)

SET(MY_PROJECT_NAME Test_1)
SET(MY_SOURCE_FILES Task_1.cpp)
SET(GLUT_INCLUDE_DIR C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\GL)
SET(GLUT_LIBRARY C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\lib\glut32.lib)

project(${MY_PROJECT_NAME})

# required libraries
find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED)
find_package(GLUT   REQUIRED)

# include directories
include_directories(
    ${GLUT_LIB_DIR}
    ${OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIR}
    ${GLUT_INCLUDE_DIR}
)

# source code files (sources *and* headers )
add_executable(${MY_PROJECT_NAME}
    ${MY_SOURCE_FILES}
)

# link against these libraries
target_link_libraries(${MY_PROJECT_NAME}
    ${GLUT_LIBRARY} 
    ${OPENGL_LIBRARY}
)
```

Answer (score 3):

Do not hardcode paths into your CMakeLists! It defeats the whole purpose of CMake as a portable build system.

If you want to override the values obtained by CMake's find script, provide the values via the command line or one of the cmake UIs (`ccmake` or `cmake-gui`).

Also be sure to check at least the [documentation](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.12/cmake.html#module%3aFindGLUT) for all find modules that you use and if that still leaves questions open, go directly to the [source code](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Modules/FindGLUT.cmake). For example, the `GLUT_LIB_DIR` variable that you use does not exist. Also, notice that the find script uses the `GLUT_ROOT_PATH` variable as a hint on the location of your local GLUT installation on Windows.

Finally, make sure that GLUT is actually installed on your machine. Visual C++ does *not* ship with GLUT by default, so you may have to download and build it yourself first.